# How to run functions with infinite loops in parallel in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm writing a template for a python script which contains two functions I would like to run in parallel with each other. There's a main function which performs some arbitrary task and a monitoring function which constantly monitors current processes to detect if any processes created in the script are terminated.

Below is the sample code from my script.

Note: I am using Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10

```py
from winsound import Beep
from psutil import pid_exists, Process
from time import sleep
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

pids = []

def monitor():
    print(pids)
    while True:
        is_valid = []
        for pid in pids:
            is_valid.append(pid_exists(int(pid)))
        if False in is_valid:
            Beep(500, 2000) # Beep simulates process termination has been detected
            for p in pids:
                Process(int(p)).kill()

def main():
    while True:
        Beep(500,100) # Constant beep simulates function is running normally
        sleep(1.5)

procs = [mp.Process(target=main),
         mp.Process(target=monitor), # Two monitoring processes are used to detect
         mp.Process(target=monitor)] # if a monitoring process was terminated

for p in procs:
    p.start()
    pids.append(str(p.pid))
    sleep(1)
for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

The problem I am having is that, while the processes do appear to be created, they do not appear to do anything within the functions such as printing or beeping. In addition to this the processes seem to end prematurely, since they shouldn't be ending unless I kill them manually.

How can I make these processes perform their roles in parallel using multiprocessing or any other library?

Comment: Is that your full code? If yes, where is the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause?
You know that 'pids' is going to be always empty. That's why your for-loop will never be executed in your `monitor()`-function

Comment: Wow, adding that clause above the procs list helped with getting the first process to do something. Now how could I get the pids into the `monitor()` function? I'm kinda stuck on that since I can only get the PID after I start the process.

Comment: Well if you use `Process` from multiprocessing than you can also give some arguments... give your function `method()` a parameter and start your Processes like that: `mp.Process(target=monitor, args=(pids,))` or instead of the tupel you can also use a list `args=[pids]`. But first of all you have to append the Processes before they start, otherwise you list `pid`will be empty if the Processes start.